# How to warp an image to a specific mask having a numpy mask in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Edit: still needing an answer!

I want to warp an image to a specific mask, which I have already created with **numpy**:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
from coords import new_contour as c

contour = np.array(c) 

tri = Delaunay(contour)

num_vertices = len(contour)
displacements = np.random.normal(0, 0.2, size=(num_vertices, 2)) 

deformed_contour = contour + displacements
deformed_contour[:, 0] = -deformed_contour[:, 0]

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.title('Original Polygon')
plt.plot(contour[:, 0], contour[:, 1], 'k')
plt.axis('equal')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.title('Deformed Polygon')
plt.plot(deformed_contour[:, 0], deformed_contour[:, 1], 'k')
plt.axis('equal')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

With this code I get this image:

[image: Original and deformed polygon]

How can I warp a 2:3 image with this polygon. For example, from this picture (adapted to the size of the polygon):

[image: original photo]

get this one:

[image: warped photo]

Thanks for your attention and have a great day!

I tried using opencv for this task, but it just gave me a black rectangle.

Edit: I have tried to create a mask with opencv directly:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("peepoDefault_1.png")

lower_green = np.array([0, 254, 0], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_green = np.array([0, 255, 0], dtype=np.uint8)

mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower_green, upper_green)

masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

cv2.imshow("Original Image", image)
cv2.imshow("Masked Image", mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It gives me a mask that i need. [image: Flag mask]

However, I still don't know how to adapt a rectangle to it

Comment: you need to know what points move where. the mask is useless because it doesn't specify that. depending on the transformation, you need to define upto four points (perspective transformation) in the source and destination space. if you want to warp a mesh instead, you need a mesh.